# отправка формы при прохождении проверки reCaptcha V2

Tags: php, recaptcha

Помогите,пожалуйста,разобраться в чем может быть проблема,а заключается она в следующем:Есть форма отправки,данные которой должны отправляться на почту по кнопке "Отправить",только при прохождении reCaptcha,но при заполнении формы и прохождении капчи,на экран выводится то,что должно выводиться,если на капче не была поставлена галочка (иными словами,если капча была проигнорирована пользователем).В чем проблема?

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
error_reporting(0);

if(!empty($_POST['send'])) {

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
    $recaptcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    if(!empty($recaptcha)) {

        $google_url="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify";
        $secret='-МОЙ СЕКРЕТНЫЙ КЛЮЧ-';
        $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $url=$google_url."?secret=".$secret."&response=".$recaptcha."&remoteip=".$ip;
        $res=SiteVerify($url);
        $res= json_decode($res, true);

        //var_dump($res);
        if($res['success']) {
            $name = substr(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['name'])), 0, 300);
            $tel = substr(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['tel'])), 0, 100);
            $email = substr(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['email'])), 0, 100);
            $message = substr(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['message'])), 0, 3000);

            $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

            $Nzakaz = rand(10000, 99999);

            $mess  = "Имя: <b>".$name."</b><br />";
            $mess .= "Телефон: <b>".$tel."</b><br />";
            $mess .= "Email: <b>".$email."</b><br />";
            $mess .= "Сообщение: <b>".$message."</b><br />";

            $theme = "Заявка Z".$Nzakaz;

            mail("mymail.com.ua@gmail.com", $theme, $mess, "From: mymail.com.ua \nContent-Type: text/html;\n charset=utf-8\nX-Priority: 0");

            echo "<h3>Заявка удачно оформлена.</h3>";
            echo "<p>Наш менеджер свяжется с вами в ближайшее время.</p>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<h2>Капча введена не верно,повторите попытку.</h2>";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<h2>Капча не заполнена.</h2>";
    }

}

}
else {

echo "<h2>Ошибка! Попробуйте еще раз.</h2>";

}

?>
```

Код формы в HTML:

```
<div id="popup">
        <div id="popup_close">
            <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/close.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <form id="contact_form" role="form" method="post" action="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/php/order.php">
            <h3>Введите номер телефона или
                электронную почту и наш мастер
                с Вами свяжется</h3>
            <input type="text" name="name"  placeholder="Имя">
            <input type="text" name="tel"  class="required" placeholder="+38 (_)__-__-_">
            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email">
            <textarea name="message" placeholder="Сообщение" rows="5"></textarea>
            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="Ключ"></div>
            <a href="#" class="btn button form_submit">
                <span class="send">
                    <svg>
              ---КОД КНОПКИ SVG--
                    </svg>
                </span>
            </a>
        </form>
    </div>
```